# Python how to import urlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, urllib

```
mirko@mirko-imedia-S2870 ~ $ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named urlib
```

I'm using python from the command line, with a fresh installation of Mint Linux 14.

What must I do to make this work?

Comment: thanks for editing, ... not all of people here are well-english-speaker ! I'm not... so why downvote ?

Comment: I assume someone down-voted because of the simplicity of the question. In general it is frowned upon questions that looks like the questioner has not put in any effort into solving it himself.

Comment: Yes, I understand, and agree

Comment: to learn more, refer: http://geeks-squad.com/using-urllib2-in-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps adding an `l` could help:

```
import urllib
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing one `l` in `urllib`, but I would highly recommend that you use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) if it is available on your installation.

Other good alternatives that requires you to install 3rd party packages are [urllib3](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3) or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks in advance, I the embdedded device I'll work on only urllib is available, so ... :)

Comment: Ah, yea then it is unavoidable. Unless you install requests. :)

Comment: If you don't use any external modules, using requests just to save a couple of lines of code is dumb, you make deployment unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Yea, for sure for a simple project @LtWorf. But, the goal of the project was not mentioned. :)

Comment: Do you evaluate complexity on amount of dependencies?

Comment: No, but using requests is way less complex then urllib in my opinion, but sure for a newbie it might be easier to use the default libraries.